# Bounty from user with less than 50 reputation

Tags: support, bounty

Today I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49398766/5468463) question which has a bounty on it. It's 50, but the bounty starter is the user (OP) with 35 reputation. How the bounty will be awarded?

Comment: Maybe he had 85 before he offered the bounty?

Comment: The bounty amount is immediately deducted from the user upon placing the bounty.

Comment: I don't see why you were hit with 7 down-votes. You asked a valid question and the answer will help many others, despite the fact that it is mentioned in bounty mechanics. Upvoted. Ask on!!!

Comment: Upvoted as well. Helped me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because before the bounty he had 50+35 reputations (The bounty amount is immediately deducted when placing the bounty, not at the ending point).

According to https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties, users needs only 75 reputation to set a bounty. So he had 85 reputations when placing the bounty.

Answer (score 3):

They had 85 reputation when they placed the bounty.

You can see the bounty being removed from their reputation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7592169/aditya-mukesh?tab=topactivity)